# I cannot figure out how to group all my html content in the same wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, css, wrapper

I am brand new to javascript, but I have a little bit of knowledge in using HTML. The problem I am facing with my website is I created an image gallery, everything works as expected, but I cannot seem to get the  content to stay inside the webpage. Here is an image of what my problem looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U19A.jpg

I have already tried setting the wrapper and body height to 100%, I have tried editing the CSS file with different display settings (e.x. absolute, relative, etc), I have tried creating a wrapper inside the article itself. None of these worked. I just want to get rid of the blocks in the webpage background and have all my content on the same page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
My HTML Code:

<!-- Title of website and page -->
<title>....:: Gallery</title>

<!-- Added variable width character encoding -->
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Compatiblility for IE and Chrome -->
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' 
content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->

<!-- Link to external CSS style sheet -->
<link href="pps.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Added tablet and mobile scaling-->
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Added older browser compatibility-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> 
</script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Script element to link to modernizer -->
<script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Added a wrapper to ensure the whole page shares the same CSS style-- >
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- Document header -->
<header>

<h1>....</h1>

<!-- Added a div class to header for image map -->
<div id="header">

<!--Added image map to HTML document-->
<map name="imgmap" id="imgmap">
<area href="https://..../" shape="rect"
coords="30,25,345,174" alt=".... Logo">
<area href="https://...../" shape="rect"
coords="500,25,845,174" alt="....">
</map>

<img src="...." usemap="#imgmap" alt="...." width="1020" height="200">
</div>
</header>               

    <nav>   <!-- Created navigation bar and an unordered list for website 
    pages -->
    <ul>    <!-- Created button class for navigation menu-->
        <li><a class="button" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="...s.html">...s</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href=".....html">...</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="....html">...</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="....html">....</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="....html">....</a></li>
        <li><a class="button" href="....html">....</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

<!-- Added a div class for the hero image of Gallery -->
<div id="galleryhero"></div>

<!-- main body of document -->
<main>

    <!-- h2 element for webpage -->
    <h2>Gallery</h2>

     <!-- Added paragraph to document -->
     <p><span class=".....">...</span> ....</p> <br>
     <h2>Images</h2>

     <!-- Create image gallery layout -->
     <article>
     <div id="leftarrow">  <!-- create id for left arrow -->
        <p>&lt;</p>  
     <figure id="fig2">  <!-- create id for figure 2 -->
        <img src="images" alt="fig2" width="360" height="202" />  
     </figure>
     <figure id="fig3">  
        <img src="images" alt="fig3" width="480" height="270" />
     </figure>
     <figure id="fig4">  
        <img src="images" alt="fig4" width="360" height="202" />
     </figure>
     <div id="rightarrow">  <!-- create id for right arrow -->
        <p>&gt;</p>  
     <div id="fiveButton">  <!-- create id for fiveButton -->
        <p>Show more images</p>  
     </div>
  </article>



   <script src="photos.js"></script>  <!-- create script src to load the 
   file photos.js -->

     <br>  <!-- Break element -->

     <!-- Added a footer to document -->
     <footer> 
     <div id="footer">

     <!-- Added an unorderedlist for footer element -->
     <ul>
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a></li> 
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a></li> 
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a><li> 
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a></li>
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a></li>
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a></li>
        <li><a href=".....html">.....</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>

             <!-- Added a copyright mark and fake e-mail address -->
             Copyright &copy; 2019 ..... <br> 
             <a href="....">....com</a>
     </footer>
    </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>


My CSS Code: 
/* Document body configurations */
body { background-color: #fffff0;  
   background: url("bg.jpg"); /* Configured background url to a root- 
absolute url */
   height: 100%;
   color: #000000; 
   font-family: Verdana, Ariel, Helvetica; }

/* Document h1 configurations */       
h1   { background-color: #FFFFFF;      
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 0.1px;
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Palatino;
   text-indent: 100%;
      white-space: nowrap; 
      overflow: hidden; }

/* Document header configurations */          
header {height: 205px;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     background: url("ppheader.gif");
     margin-bottom: 0;
     padding-bottom: 50px;
     border-style: solid;    
     border-color: #000000;    
     color: #000000;
     font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Palatino;  }

/* Document h2 configurations */         
h2   { background-color: #fffff0; 
   color: #e65c00;
   text-align: center;     
   font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Palatino; }

/* Document h3 configurations */       
h3   { color: #000033; 
     float:left; }

/* Document main body configurations */      
main { padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   display: block;
   background-color: #fffff0; 
   margin-left: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 300px;
   padding-top: 1px; }

/* Document configurations for buttons */   
.button { display: block;
      width: 10em;
      padding: 1em;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #000000;
      font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 1px solid white;
      margin: 0;
      text-decoration: none; }

/* Document image gallery configurations */       
figure  { display: inline-block;
       list-style-type: none; 
       width: 269px;
       height: 448px; }

/* Added a caption for videos */       
figure figcaption  {width: 269px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #f4f4f0;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-style: italic;
 font-family: Helvetica, serif; }

/* Document button configurations */
.button:link { color: #FFFFFF; }
.button:visited { color: #ffe066; }
.button:hover { color: #990000; }

/* Document navigation bar configurations */
nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

nav li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Document header, navigation, main body, and footer display 
configurations */
header, nav, main, footer { display: block; }

/* Document table configurations */
table      { margin: auto;
         border: 1px solid #982e01;
         width: 90%; 
         border-collapse: collapse; }

td         { text-align: center; }

th, td     { padding: 5px;
         border: 1px solid #982e01; }  

/* Document paragraph configurations */
    #text      { text-align: left; }

tr:first-of-type { background-color: #000000;
               color: #FFFFFF; } 

tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #fffecc; }

dt   { color: #000033;
      font-weight: bold; }

.paulpaintservice { color: #982e01;
      font-size: 1.2em; }

/* Document logo configurations */        
      .logo    { color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 3em; }

/* Document footer configurations */          
footer  { font-size: .70em;
       font-style: italic; 
       text-align: center;
       padding: 10px; 
       margin-top: 100px;
       background-color: #fffff0;
       margin-left: 5px; }

 #footer ul { text-align: center; list-style-type: none; }

 #footer li { display: inline;
         background-color: #fffff0; }

 #footer a  { padding: 2px 10px; }

 /* Document box style configurations */
 *        { box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Document wrapper configurations that create a box model for the 
website */
#wrapper { background-color: #000000; 
       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;
       height: 100%;
       min-width: 700px; 
       max-width: 1024px;
       box-shadow:  5px 5px 5px #1e1e1e; }

 /* Document hero image configurations for the home, services, gallery, 
 about, and appointment pages */           
 #homehero  { height: 300px;
         background-image: url("hsunset3.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%; 
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 1px; }

 #servicehero   { height: 300px; 
         background-image: url("hsunset2.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat; 
         margin-left: 1px; }

 #galleryhero { height: 300px; 
         background-image: url("hsunset.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 1px; }

#abouthero  { height: 300px; 
         background-image: url("hevening.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 1px; }

#projecthero { height: 300px; 
         background-image: url("hocean.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 1px; }

#securityhero { height: 300px; 
         background-image: url("hfield.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 1px; }             

#appointmenthero { height: 300px; 
         background-image: url("hvalley.jpg");
         background-size: 100% 100%;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
         margin-left: 1px; }

/* Configure pc.gif to float to the left on "About" page */
#pc         { float: left;
          margin: 0 16px 16px 0;
          border: 2px ridge black;
          border-radius: 5px;
          background: #FFFFFF;}

/* Document "About" page paragraph configurations */              
p           { text-align: left;
          font-size: 1.2em; }

/* Document "Gallery" configurations */           
#gallery    { position: relative; }

#gallery ul { width: fill; list-style-type: none; }

#gallery img { border: 1px solid black;
           margin: 10px; }

#gallery a  { text-decoration: none; color: #e65c00; font-style: italic;
          font-family: Helvetica; 
          font-weight: bold; }

#gallery span { display: none; }

#gallery li { display: inline-block; }

#gallery a:hover span {display: block; 
                   position: absolute; 
                   left: 300px; 
                   top: 0;
                   text-align: center; 
                   text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000; }

/* Document navigation configurations */                       
nav a      { text-decoration: none; }
nav a:link { color: #FFFFFF; }
nav a:visited { color: #ffe066; }
nav a:hover { color: #FFFFFF; }


nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

nav li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Document header, navigation, main body, and footer display 
configurations */
header, nav, main, footer { display: block; }
label { float: left;
    width: 8em;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 1em; }

/* Document contact form configurations */      
input, textarea { margin-bottom: 1em;
              margin-top: 1.2em; 
              display: block; }

/* Configure <form> */
#mySubmit { margin-left: 10em; }
#mobile    { display: none; }
#desktop   { display: inline; }

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* reset rules */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}

blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

/* main content */
article {
background: white;
position: relative;
}

article h2 {
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
margin: 0 0 10px 51px;
}

#leftarrow, #rightarrow {
background: #696565;
color: white;
position: absolute;
z-index: 30;
text-align: center;
height: 135px;
width: 40px;
top: 67px;
}

article div:hover {
cursor: default;
}

#leftarrow {
left: 0;
}

#rightarrow {
right: 0;
}

#fiveButton {
display: block;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 290px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

#fiveButton p {
width: 20%;
margin: 0 auto;
line-height: 2em;
background: #696565;
}

#leftarrow p, #rightarrow p {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -0.5em;
}

figure {
position: absolute;
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50),
                   -10px 0px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50);
-moz-box-shadow:    10px 0px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50),
                   -10px 0px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50);
box-shadow:         10px 0px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50),
                   -10px 0px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

#fig2 {
z-index: 10;
left: 13%;
top: 34px;
}

#fig3 {
z-index: 20;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -240px;
top: 0;
} 

#fig4 {
z-index: 10;
right: 13%;
top: 34px;
}

/* Document configurations for mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)

/* Document body configurations */
{
body       { margin: 0; 
         padding: 0;
         background-image: none; }

/* Document wrapper configurations */            
#wrapper   { min-width: 0;
         margin: 0;
         box-shadow: none; }

/* Document h1 configurations */             
h1         { margin: 0; }

/* Document navigation configurations */
nav        { float: none;
         width: auto;
         padding: 0.5em; }

nav li     { display: inline-block; }

nav a      { padding: 1em; }

/* Document main body configurations */
main       { padding: 1em;
         margin-left: 0;
         font-size: 90%; }

/* Document footer configurations */             
footer     { margin: 0; }

/* Document hero image configurations */
#homehero  { margin-left: 0; }

#servicehero  { margin-left: 0; }

#galleryhero { margin-left: 0; }

#abouthero  { margin-left: 0; }

#appointmenthero { margin-left: 0; }

#projecthero { margin-left: 0; }

#securityhero { margin-left: 0; }

/* Document logo configurations */
.logo      { margin-left: 0; }
}

/* Document configurations for mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

/* Document h1 configurations */    
h1         { height: 100%;
         font-size: 1.5em;
         padding-left: 0.3em; 
         background: none; }

/* Document navigation configurations */             
nav        { padding: 0; }

nav a      { display: block; 
         padding: 0.2em;
         font-size: 1.3em;
         border-bottom: 1px;
         border-color: #330000; }

nav ul     { margin : 0;
         padding: 0; }

nav li     { display: block; 
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0; } 

/* Document button configurations */             
.button    { width: auto; }    

/* Document main body configurations */      
main       { padding-top: 0.1em;
         padding-right: 0.6em; 
         padding-bottom: 0.1em;
         padding-left: 0.4em; }

/* Document hero image configurations */             
#homehero   { display: none; }

#servicehero   { display: none; }

#galleryhero  { display: none; }

#abouthero  { display: none; }

#appointmenthero { display: none; }

#projecthero { display: none; }

#securityhero { display: none; }

/* Document footer configurations */
footer      { padding: 0; }

/* Document mobile, desktop, and header display options configurations */
#mobile     { display: inline; }

/* Disable desktop mode while on mobile device */
#desktop    { display: none; }

/* Disable header image while on mobile device */
#header      { display: none; }
}
```

Here is my image gallery JS code:

```
"use strict"; // interpret document contents in JavaScript strict mode

/* global variables */
var photoOrder = [1,2,3,4,5];  

var figureCount = 3;  

/* Add src values to img elements based on order specified in photoOrder 
array */
function populateFigures() {  
var filename;  
var currentFig;  

if (figureCount === 3) {  

//Add for loop with 3 interations and increments i by 1 after each loop
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
filename = "images/IMG_0" + photoOrder[i] + "sm.jpg"; 
currentFig = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i - 1]; 
currentFig.src = filename; 
  }

//Else statement and for loop with 6 iterations 
} else {
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
filename = "images/IMG_0" + photoOrder[i] + "sm.jpg";  

currentFig = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i];  
currentFig.src = filename;  
   }
 }
}

/* shift all images one figure to the left, and change values in photoOrder 
array to match  */
rightArrow() {
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   
after each cycle
  if ((photoOrder[i] + 1) === 6) {  
     photoOrder[i] = 1;  
  } else {               
     photoOrder[i] += 1;
  }
  populateFigures();  //Call populateFigures()
 }
}

/* shift all images one figure to the right, and change values in photoOrder 
array to match  */
function leftArrow() {
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
  if ((photoOrder[i] - 1) === 0) {  
with index i minus 1 is equal to the value of 0
     photoOrder[i] = 5;   
  } else {
     photoOrder[i] -= 1;   
  }
  populateFigures();  //Call populateFigures()
 }
}

/* switch to 3-image layout */
function previewThree() {   
var articleEl = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];  
var numberButton = document.querySelector("#fiveButton p");  

/*  Remove the 1st and 5th figure elements */
articleEl.removeChild(document.getElementById("fig1"));  
articleEl.removeChild(document.getElementById("fig5"));  

figureCount = 3;  
numberButton.innerHTML = "Show more images";   
 if (numberButton.addEventListener) {  
numberButton.removeEventListener("click", previewThree,
 false);
numberButton.addEventListener("click", previewFive, false);  
} else if (numberButton.attachEvent) {
numberButton.detachEvent("onclick", previewThree);  
numberButton.attachEvent("onclick", previewFive);  
 }
}

/* switch to 5-image layout */
function previewFive() {
var articleEl = document.getElementsByTagName("article")[0]; 
//Create figure and img elements for 5th image
var lastFigure = document.createElement("figure"); 

//Configure settings for 5th figure 
lastFigure.id = "fig5"; 
lastFigure.style.zIndex = "5"; 
lastFigure.style.position = "absolute"; 
lastFigure.style.right = "45px";  
lastFigure.style.top = "67px";    

var lastImage = document.createElement("img");  
lastImage.width = "240";  
lastImage.height = "135"; 

lastFigure.appendChild(lastImage); 
articleEl.appendChild(lastFigure);  

//clone figure element for fifth image and edit to be first image
var firstFigure = lastFigure.cloneNode(true);  

/* Change the id value for the firstFigure node from fig5 and the value
cloned from the lastFigure node to fig1, remove cloned value for the right 
CSS style and specify a new value for the left CSS style */
firstFigure.id = "fig1";  
firstFigure.style.right = "";  
string
firstFigure.style.left = "45px";  

//Use the appendChild() method to add the firstFigure node to document tree
//articleEl.appendChild(firstFigure);

articleEl.insertBefore(lastFigure, 
document.getElementById("rightarrow")); 

/* Insert the firstFigure node before the existing element with the id 
value 
fig2 */
articleEl.insertBefore(firstFigure,  
document.getElementById("fig2"));

//Change from 3 images to 5 when user switches to viewing 5 photos
figureCount = 5;  //Assign an image for each img element

//Add appropriate src values to two new img elements
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/IMG_0" + photoOrder[0] 
+ "sm.jpg";  
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[4].src = "images/IMG_0" + photoOrder[4] 
+ "sm.jpg";  

//change button to hide extra images
var numberButton = document.querySelector("#fiveButton p");  //Assign var 
numberButton value to the selector element with id #fiveButton p
numberButton.innerHTML = "Show fewer images";  //Assign the innerHTML 
numberButton to the attribute show fewer images
 if (numberButton.addEventListener) {  
numberButton.removeEventListener("click", previewFive,
 false);  //Remove 5-image view
numberButton.addEventListener("click", previewThree,
 false);
} else if (numberButton.attachEvent) {  /* Add else-if statement to switch 
between a preview of 5 or 3 images */
numberButton.detachEvent("onclick", previewFive);  
numberButton.attachEvent("onclick", previewThree);  
 }
}

/* create event listeners for left arrow, right arrow, and
center figure element  
*/
function createEventListeners() {
var leftarrow = document.getElementById("leftarrow"); //create var named 
leftarrow and assign value to the element with the id value leftarrow

//if/else statement to create the event listener for the left navigation 
arrow
if (leftarrow.addEventListener) {  
leftarrow.addEventListener("click", leftArrow, false);
} else if (leftarrow.attachEvent) {  
leftarrow.attachEvent("onclick", leftArrow);
  }

/* create a variable and assign an event listener for the right navigation 
arrow */
var rightarrow = document.getElementById("rightarrow"); //create var named 
rightarrow and assign value to the element with the id value rightarrow
if (rightarrow.addEventListener) {  
rightarrow.addEventListener("click", rightArrow, false);
} else if (rightarrow.attachEvent) {  
rightarrow.attachEvent("onclick", rightArrow);
}  

//Add event listener for the third img element in the document that has index 
value 2 
var mainFig = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[1];  //Create var variable 
mainFig and assign value to the second image element with the index value of 
1

//Add if-else statement to create the event listener to call zoomFig() when 
user clicks the center image
  if (mainFig.addEventListener) {  //Add if statement to not zoom into image 
if it is not clicked
mainFig.addEventListener("click", zoomFig, false);
} else if (mainFig.attachEvent) {  //Add else-if statement to zoom into image 
when clicked
mainFig.attachEvent("onclick", zoomFig);
  }
  var showAllButton = document.querySelector("#fiveButton p");  //Assign var 
showAllButton value to the selector element with id #fiveButton p
  if (showAllButton.addEventListener) {  
showAllButton.addEventListener("click", previewFive, false);
} else if (showAllButton.attachEvent) {  
showAllButton.attachEvent("onclick", previewFive); 
  }
}


/* open center figure in separate window */
function zoomFig() {
var propertyWidth = 960;  //Assign var propertyWidth value to 960px 
var propertyHeight = 600;  //Assign var propertyHeight value to 600px
var winLeft = ((screen.width - propertyWidth) / 2);  // Create var named 
winLeft and start with the width of the existing browser window minus the 
width of the new browser window, divided by two
var winTop = ((screen.height - propertyHeight) / 2);  // Create var named 
winTop and start with the height of the existing browser window minus the 
width of the new browser window, divided by two
var winOptions = "width=960,height=600";  //Create var named winOptions and 
assign to the width of 960px and height of 600px 
winOptions += ",left=" + winLeft;  //Create an option string for the 
window.open() method that incorporates the calculated values for the left of 
window
winOptions += ",top=" + winTop;  //Create an option string for the 
window.open() method that incorporates the calculated values for the top of 
window
var zoomWindow = window.open("zoom.htm", "zoomwin", "width=960,height=600");  
//Create variable named zoomWindow and assign to the window created by 
window.open to display contents of zoom html file  
zoomWindow.focus();  //Make the external photo gallery window the active 
window
}

/* create event listeners and populate image elements */
function setUpPage() {  //Call function
createEventListeners();  //Call function
populateFigures();  //Call function
}

/* run setUpPage() function when page finishes loading */
if (window.addEventListener) {  
window.addEventListener("load", setUpPage, false); 
} else if (window.attachEvent)  {  

window.attachEvent("onload", setUpPage);
}
```

Another bizarre thing that happened was that the logo/header image loads at first, then it immediately switches to one of the image gallery photos. I could not figure out how to fix that...

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without looking at your gallery JS code. My guesses are: 1) gallery code makes some part of your HTML absolutely positioned, and thus, that part of the page shifts out of place, and solution would be making immediate container relatively positioned (`style="position: relative;"`), but can't say for sure without looking at the code; 2) image is replaced because gallery code wants some placeholder image for manipulations, or maybe because you need to specify some container where it should look for input list of images. Again, need to see code to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited my initial post with my gallery javascript code. It never occurred to me that this error may be caused by the display settings in the js file, I assumed it had to be the CSS file.

Comment: This line -- `currentFig = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i - 1];` -- grabs first image on the page and replaces it. I think this code was meant to run in a very simple webpage, maybe in `iframe`. Could be fixed, but if you're not married to it, maybe try some more universal solution? I belive lots of solutions exist these days, and many of them specifically designed to be easily inserted by inexperienced people (no offense, web coding is wildly popular these days, all levels of coding experence are possible).

Comment: Thank you again for your response,  unfortunately, my instructor wants us to use the method in our textbook that was required for this class. They said, "Add an image gallery to one of the pages on your website. The image gallery should be similar to the one created in Chapter 5. The following elements should be included:"

At least 3 images.
The ability to scroll through the images using right and left arrows (you may copy the HTML/CSS code used to create the arrows from the Chapter assignment 
The ability to click on an image and have it zoom in and show a larger version of the image.

Comment: I see. This means your original gallery code must be modified, and these modifications won't be light. Also, as this is some kind of task, I feel like I can't give you ready code. But feel free to try it yourself and ask for help, if needed. Maybe in separate questions.